# Smart Contract ICO

Tags: exchanges, ico, etherdelta

Assuming that I created a fully-functioning smart contract for a NEW COIN, is the same smart contract required when I wanted it listed on e.g. ETHERDELTA?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the ERC20 Token Standard, you can find more information here:

- https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
- https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exchanges la EtherDelta will list your token contract as long as it is ERC20 compliant.